# Angular: how do I init module (or service) with parameters?

Tags: angularjs, module

I need to create a module that will be used by different applications.
Each application is using its own set of vars (application name, REST urls, ...).

How do I set inner variable, by the hosting application, in module (or in service)?

Need to init these parameters as soon as possible as the application loads.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module have a provider. That way the client application can bootstrap configuration.

Read the "Provider Recipe" section on [angular's site](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) for an example of this.

> You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts. This is usually interesting only for reusable services whose behavior might need to vary slightly between applications.

Comment: With using this provider, how do I store the configured data for all parts of the module to be able to access?     Let's say there is a service, in this module, that needs a string that was configured.       Thanks.

Comment: Just store the configuration data within the provider and then it can be accessed anywhere you inject that provider. A provider is just like any other service (or rather, a service/factory/value is just a provider). Have a look at the provider example on [this page](http://blog.xebia.com/2013/09/01/differences-between-providers-in-angularjs/).